# Best data type I can use for a parameter of format <index, value> in java

Tags: java

I  want to use a data type for having the format as  for exg<1,0.2332>
.I don't want it be a an array ,just a single value , if that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to come up with your own bean class, you could use one of the various Tuple or Pair classes, such as the one in [Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html):

```
Pair<Integer, Double> p = new ImmutablePair<>(1,0.2332);
```

Comment: "If you don't want to come up with your own bean class": Usually, that is a good approach, though. See @Jason's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that contains the parts you need, then use that class for your parameter value type.

E.g:

```
public class X {
    public int partA;
    public double partB;
}
```

Of course you could make the parts private and set them in the constuctor and provide getters and a `.equals()` method.